# Font looks weird on mac

Tags: css, macos

I have developed one website
http://yournextleap.com/work-with-yournextleap
under `<p>` tag all fonts having #333, It looks fine in firefox and other browsers even safari on windows,
But when am looking same thing on mac pc, It looks faint gray color, Can anyone help me, Thanks advance

Comment: Put `font-weight` to something higher than 100. Browsers all render `font-weight` differently, Safari OSX makes it light grey for me too, but up the font-weight to about 300 and it looks fine.

Comment: Set it to what you want. See here [Css Font Weight](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp)

Comment: I mean to say font-weight: normal

Comment: Obviously you're not targeting people over 50 because I can't read text that small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the `font-weight` set to 100 which is *very* light. When I changed it to 200 it was much easier to read on Chrome OS X

Comment: That's a possibility too, however Helvetica Neue supports several weights between `font-weight: lighter` and `font-weight: normal` which is why I was advocating using integer weights this time.

Answer (score 1):

use a different font.  thats all you can do, bigger, wider, heavier....

```
font-weight:normal;
```

also, some might argue that #333 for a font color is a design flaw.